# Gimpfu scripting: Why does layer's ID get corrupted?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gimp, gimpfu

I have been experimenting with GIMP(v2.8.10) layer's manipulation, programatically with custom gimpfu plug-ins. I successfully achieved to select, rotate, scale and translate dinamically a portion of the existing layer:

#### Some of the code inside the plug-in:

Simplified for relevance. All these instructions work.

```
# I only use one layer in the probe image
layer = img.layers[0]

selection = pdb.gimp_rect_select(img, init_coords[0], init_coords[1],
                                            my_width,my_height,2,0,0)

# Copy and paste selection
pdb.gimp_edit_copy(layer)
float_layer = pdb.gimp_edit_paste(layer, 1)

# Transform floating selection step by step
float_layer = pdb.gimp_item_transform_rotate_simple(float_layer, 
                                             ROTATE_90, 1, 0, 0)
float_layer = pdb.gimp_layer_scale(float_layer, new_width,new_height, 1)
float_layer = pdb.gimp_layer_translate(float_layer, h_offset, 0)
```

#### The problem

- If I remove the last line(`gimp_layer_translate`), everything else works.
- Else, if I remove the line containing `gimp_layer_scale` instead, everything else works.
- But if I try to use all these functions together, `gimp_layer_translate` crashes with `RuntimeError`

> The procedure gimp-layer-translate has been called with incorrect ID for «layer» arg. Probably is trying to operate with an unexisting layer.

I don't know why it fails like this. *If they work individually, why not together?* I wonder.

#### References

I use to start from the `template.py` in [gimpbook.com](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/) as a starting point to build the plug-ins, due to it seems to have a solid structure to enclose the code into "undo blocks".  My main source of information about `pdb` is [this website](http://www.efalk.org/Docs/Python/gimp_0.html) that I found on Google. Also, I found some of the procedures I needed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549908/python-fu-select-copy-paste).

Also, one of my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402897/where-can-i-select-my-personal-plugins-in-gimp) may help as a reference on how to start making custom plug-ins for gimp.

#### What keeps me stuck

I'm not sure if the cause is a gimp's bug or my code is wrongly implemented. Due to some of the code posted on the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549908/python-fu-select-copy-paste), I am wondering if I am overkilling the available memory (after all, I didn't know that I had to destroy the objects with an specific procedure call until I found out on that answer). *What happens if I don't delete them?* I wonder. *Will they persist in RAM until I close GIMP, or will they generate persistent files that will flood the GIMP system?* Honestly, I have no idea about the consequences of ignoring this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the assignment when working with the layer. Here is how you destroy the float_layer variable:

```
# This creates a new layer that you assign to the float_layer
float_layer = pdb.gimp_item_transform_rotate_simple(float_layer, 
                                             ROTATE_90, 1, 0, 0)
# This does not return anything at all, it works with the layer in-place.
# But you overwrite the float_layer variable anyway, destroying it.
float_layer = pdb.gimp_layer_scale(float_layer, new_width,new_height, 1)
# This does not work because float_layer is no longer referencing the layer at all
float_layer = pdb.gimp_layer_translate(float_layer, h_offset, 0)
```

So do this instead:

```
float_layer = pdb.gimp_item_transform_rotate_simple(float_layer, 
                                             ROTATE_90, 1, 0, 0)
pdb.gimp_layer_scale(float_layer, new_width,new_height, 1)
pdb.gimp_layer_translate(float_layer, h_offset, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by switching the floating_layer to a new `Layer` instance, before executing those two functions.

```
fixed_layer = gimp.Layer(img, 'float_layer', int(gh), int(gw),
                                           RGBA_IMAGE, 100, 1)
```

So I make the following combination:

```
# Transform floating selection step by step
float_layer = pdb.gimp_item_transform_rotate_simple(float_layer, 
                                             ROTATE_90, 1, 0, 0)
fixed_layer = gimp.Layer(img, 'float_layer', new_width, new_height,
                                           RGBA_IMAGE, 100, 1)
fixed_layer = pdb.gimp_layer_scale(float_layer, new_width,new_height, 1)
fixed_layer = pdb.gimp_layer_translate(float_layer, h_offset, 0)
```

The problem seems to be that, after executing some procedures over the layer, it becomes `None` (it's like if it was automatically removed from memory...). This solution allows me to execute 2 or 3 more operations... It's not a complete solution. I'll keep researching

Comment: It sees you didn't pay enough attention on the @Emil's answer: These procedrues you are calling **do not** return a resulting layer! They transform the layer internally. Just stop prefixing your calls with `fixed_layer = ` 0 the first layer you reference at te beggining of your script remains a valid reference.

Comment: jsbueno, to be fair SabsSBM posted this before I posted my answer. This answer works but for the wrong reasons.